# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'beforeCommand') when referencing elements

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, webdriver-io

I'm following a WebdriverIO course which is using https://demo.learnwebdriverio.com/ as its test application.

I have a page object file (Home.page.js) with the following code:

```js
class Home extends Generic {
  constructor(){
    super('./');
  }

  get $$feedTabs () { return $$('[data-qa-id="feed-tabs"] [data-qa-type="feed-tab"]') }
  get feedTabsText () { return this.$$feedTabs.map($tab => $tab.getText()); }
  get activeFeedTabText() { return this.$$('[data-qa-id="feed-tabs"] [data-qa-type="feed-tab"] .active').map($tab => $tab.getText());  }

}
```

These getters work just fine with the following passing test code:

```js
        it('should show both feed tabs', async function () {
            await expect(await home.feedTabsText).toEqual(['Your Feed', 'Global Feed']);
        });

        it('should default to showing the global feed', async function () {
            // get all tabs with an 'active' class, check only one returns with correct text
            await expect(await home.activeFeedTabText).toEqual(['Global Feed']);
        });
```

However, if I change the last getter to this:

```js
  get activeFeedTabText() { return this.$$feedTabs.$$('.active').map($tab => $tab.getText());  }
```

I will get this error when running the test: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'beforeCommand')`, with reference to the second test.

Why is this happening?